# node-gyp build on windows 10

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I tried to install a package with npm, and i get the following :

```
C:\Users\joube\Google Drive\Informatique\wikipedia-to-mongodb\node_modules\xml-stream\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Python27/python.exe -c import platform; print(platform.python_version());
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\joube\Google Drive\Informatique\wikipedia-to-mongodb\node_modules\xml-stream\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v4.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! iconv@2.1.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@2.1.11 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the iconv package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls iconv
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\joube\Google Drive\Informatique\wikipedia-to-mongodb\npm-debug.log
```

I saw that there was a very common problem, I triedd solving it by instlliing Visual C++ Desktop Edition, but it didn't work. Can you help me to find wht is wrong ?

Thank you.

**Edit**

After doing a clean install of python, I get this error :

```
npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Génération des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la génération en parallèle, ajoutez le commutateur "/m".
TRACKER : error TRK0005: échec de localisation de : "CL.exe". Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. [C:\Users\joube\Goog
le Drive\Informatique\wikipedia-to-mongodb\node_modules\xml-stream\node_modules\iconv\build\libiconv.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\joube\Google Drive\Informatique\wikipedia-to-mongodb\node_modules\xml-stream\node_modules\iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v4.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\joube\Google Drive\Informatique\wikipedia-to-mongodb\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Looking at the logs, the line `Error: Command failed: /Python27/python.exe` makes me suspect you might need to install Python 2.7.

Comment: It is already installed..

Comment: I've done a clean install and now this is not the same error, see Edit in the question